# Cannot find module 'watchpack'

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, angular9, serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'watchpack'
Require stack:

- G:\xampp\htdocs\trends\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js
- G:\xampp\htdocs\trends\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
- G:\xampp\htdocs\trends\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js

........
and lot more similar issues for "watchpack"

Please help!!

[image]

Comment: `npm update --force`

Answer (score 2):

try to update npm using

```
npm update --force
```

after that delete node_modules and run

```
npm i
```

it's worked for me hope it'll work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try removing node_modules folder and doing an `npm install` otherwise try to just install  it with `npm install watchpack`

Comment: It works with me by: npm install watchpack directly, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in China, please use `cnpm` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cnpm) instead of npm. Then run `cnpm upgrade` and `cnpm install`